# C# WPF => commands doesn't work though binding and using ICommand. Compiler doesn't throw any exception

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

!!! SOLVED, THANK YOU VERY MUCH !!!

I'm writing my first MVVM application (in WPF C#). Because of that, I want to use commands instead "Click" event defined in a view. The command, which I want to induce is really simple, it should to create and open a view.

1. I have written RelayCommand class which inherits ICommand interface.

```
      internal class RelayCommand : ICommand
      {
          readonly Action<object> _execute;
          readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    
          public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
          {
              _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
              _canExecute = canExecute;
          }
    
          public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
          {
              return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
          }
    
          public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
          {
              add
              {
                  CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
              }
              remove
              {
                  CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
              }
          }
    
          public void Execute(object parameter)
          {
              _execute(parameter);
          }
      }
```

2. I write a method changing value of the field, which represent a view.

   ```
   private bool openSoundsWindow;
   private bool openChordsWindow;

   public bool OpenSoundsWindow
   {
      get { return openSoundsWindow; }
      set { openSoundsWindow = value; }
   }

   public bool OpenChordsWindow
   { 
      get { return openChordsWindow; }
      set { openChordsWindow = value; }
   }

   public void OpenSounds()
   {
      openSoundsWindow = true;
   }

   public void OpenChords()
   {
      OpenChordsWindow = true;
   }
   ```
3. I wrote in view model class commands by RelayCommand and OnPropertyChanged event. View model class inherits INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
private MainModel model = new MainModel();
 
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 
  private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
       PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
 
 public bool OpenSoundsWindow
 {
       get { return model.OpenSoundsWindow; }
 
       set
       {
           model.OpenSoundsWindow = value;
           OnPropertyChanged(nameof(OpenSoundsWindow));
       }
  }
 
private ICommand openSounds = null;
 
 public ICommand OpenSounds
 {
       get
       {
            if (openSounds == null)
            {
                 openChords = new RelayCommand(
                  (object o) =>
                   {
                       model.OpenSounds();
                       OnPropertyChanged(nameof(OpenSoundsWindow));
                       var newSoundsWindow = new Sounds();
                       newSoundsWindow.Show();
                   },
                   (object o) =>
                   {
                       return model.OpenSoundsWindow != null;
                  });
            }
 
             return openSounds;
         }
  }
```

4. I created instance of view model in view's xaml code.

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:HearingTeacher.ViewModels" 
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:MainViewModel}"
 
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:MainViewModel x:Key="mainViewModel" />
    </Window.Resources>
```

5. I binded property command for buttons with created commands in view model.

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Sounds" Command="{Binding Path=OpenSounds, 
            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Compiler doesn't throw any exception, and .NET starts an application correctly, but commands doesn't work.

Comment: "commands doesn't work" - did you set a breakpoint in your command implementation and verified that it is not called?

Comment: In (4) you create a view model as a *resource*, but I can't see anything setting that to the window's `DataContext`. Did you mean to set `Window.DataContext`?

Comment: @KlausGütter Do you mean breakpoints in compiler? Yes I tried, and debugger doesn't react, I guess it means that a command isn't executing

Comment: @CharlesMager I added in datacontext, and it didn't work. When I delete in resources and added in datacontext it works! Thank you very much, bro! But now when I click button "Chords" souns window is opening, I don't know what is going on.

Comment: We don't have all the code, but it's probably because your `OpenSounds` getter sets the `openChords` field and that's what's returned by `OpenChords`.

Comment: Nope, getters and setters operate on correctly varues:  ```public bool OpenSoundsWindow
        {
            get { return openSoundsWindow; }
            set { openSoundsWindow = value; }
        }```

Comment: Setup OpenSounds in the constructor. Use Action<object, bool> instead of Predicate<object> as canExecute type, and remove the add/remove in the event CanExecuteChanged, using only public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged; without add and remove. Test and tell us if it works

Comment: @jalepi When I changed type Action <object, bool> instead of Predicate <obcject> in RelayCommands class Visual Studio throws an exception in CanExecute method "element _canExecute" doesn't have null value here

Comment: SOLVED! I changed Predicate <object> on Func <object, bool>, and changed one variable in ICommand getter and everything is fine. Thank you very much, guys! You are wonderful and helpful.

Comment: Sorry, that was very dumb of me. It is Func<object, bool> :D